# How to add logo to a web3 personal signature message?

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, react, express

I have generated a signature message from my react js app for the users. But in mobile metamask the message displays a letter D, the first letter of my url, at the top of the message.

But I want to show the site icon in the place of that 'D'

```
 <link rel ="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico"/>
```

I used this tag but it didn't add any image to the signature message

```
let signature = await web3.eth.personal.sign(res.message, account)
```

This is the code I used.

> module.exports = {
> firstPart: 'x'
>
> ```
> secondPart:'x'
>
> "URI:url ,
>
> Nonce:nonce,    Issued:date    }
> ```

My message

[image: The way it is displayed now, in my case D is displayed in place of T]

[image: How I want it to display]